# Alternative Syntax When Defining Implicit?

Tags: scala

Given the following:

```
scala> trait Foo { def get: String = "get" }
defined trait Foo
```

I implemented it and made an implicit:

```
scala> case class FooImpl(x: String) extends Foo {
     |   override def get = s"got $x"
     | }
defined class FooImpl

scala> implicit val fooImpl = FooImpl("yo")
fooImpl: FooImpl = FooImpl(yo)
```

Lastly, I tried to write a method that implicitly resolves a `Foo`, returning `get` on that implicitly resolved class.

```
scala> def f[A: Foo](x: A) = x.get
<console>:11: error: Foo does not take type parameters
       def f[A: Foo](x: A) = x.get
              ^
<console>:11: error: value get is not a member of type parameter A
       def f[A: Foo](x: A) = x.get
                               ^
```

But I got the above errors.

So I re-wrote it using the `implicit` keyword:

```
scala> def f(implicit x: Foo): String = x.get
f: (implicit x: Foo)String

scala> f
res0: String = got yo
```

Is it possible to re-write this example to not explicitly specify the `implicit` keyword?

Note - it's possible that I'm confusing this notation with [TypeTag](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html) under the section, `Using a Context bound of a Type Parameter`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong syntax, what you want is an upper bound:

```
scala> def f[A <: Foo](x: A) = x.get
f: [A <: Foo](x: A)String
```

Where you're saying that `A` is a subtype of `Foo` and that tells the compiler that `A` does have a method called `get`.

The syntax you're using (`:`) means that there's an implicit conversion from `A` to `Foo[A]`, the problem is that `Foo` doesn't take a type parameter, you can also check it into the REPL where the column syntax is translated to an implicit parameter:

```
scala> trait Foo2[T]
defined trait Foo2

scala> def g[T: Foo2](x: Int): Int = x
g: [T](x: Int)(implicit evidence$1: Foo2[T])Int
```